# Migrating millions of rows based on derived data in CockroachDB?

Tags: database, database-migration, cockroachdb

For the purpose of this post, I'm going to over simplify my data model to just the necessary pieces.

I have a data model that looks like this...

```
table Workspace {
  id
}

table Posts {
  id
  workspaceId
  typeId      
}

table PostTypes {
  id
  typeName
  workspaceId
}
```

This data model was originally used as I figured that that there would be all sorts of `Post` types and that this way I could let the list grow. That is not the case anymore. There is also an issue with this model in that both `Post` and `PostTypes` both point at `Workspace` but there is no DB level validation to make sure the relation between the 3 is setup right.

What I want to move to for both performance and correctness is something like...

```
enum PostType {
  BLOG,
  PERSONAL,
  ... etc
}

table Posts {
  id          String
  workspaceId String
  postType    PostType
}
```

I can think of naive solutions on how to migrate all this data. I.e. iterate through the rows using my ORM and properly assign the `postType` one by one, but for millions of rows that would take forever. Im worried about writing some type of naive migration will cause performance issues in my DB while it's running, and it needs to continue to support production.

There has got to be a "proper" way to do something like this and I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways that I can think of off the top of my head.

Approach I:

1. Create a new column `postType` in `Posts`;
2. Update `Posts` table to fill in this `post_type` with correct value (e.g. `UPDATE posts SET postType = postType.postType FROM postType WHERE typeId = postType.id`)
3. Drop the `postTypeId` column from `Posts`.

However, step 2 and 3 might take a while as it involves backfilling the table, and can block your workload that touches the `Posts` table.

Approach II:

1. Create a new table `Posts_new`;
2. Direct your writes to both `Posts` and `Posts_new`, and copy the table from `Posts` to `Posts_new`;
3. Read from both tables afterwards to "compare results" and gain confidence over time that "both tables are up-to-date".
4. Flip `Posts_new` to be primary and `Posts` to be shadow.

I learned about this approach from this Doordash tech [blog](https://doordash.engineering/2023/02/07/how-we-scaled-new-verticals-fulfillment-backend-with-cockroachdb/) on how they migrated from another DB to CockroachDB, so maybe you will find it helpful.

Approach III:

Don't do a migration at all. Leave `Posts` as is but change your application code to use `Posts.postTypeID` since it only has a few well-defined values (e.g. 0, 1, 2). Then drop the `PostTypes` table or leave it as a form of documentation.